# Is it possible to remove the 'Tiles' and 'Content' views completely from Windows 10 file explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I have never found the Tiles or Content views useful. But the ways to tell Windows to stop showing them don't seem reliable any more.

Is there a way to just completely remove them from the OS?

[image: Windows 10 File Explorer Ribbon]

Comment: You should edit your question to show what you are seeing. I do not see anything untoward in my Windows 10 VM..  In File Explorer, View, use smaller icons, even details and much noise will disappear.

Comment: No, I really do want the views removed. Windows keeps showing Content and Tiles in search results and when I navigate to folders with "media" in spite of configuration, registry edits, reboots, and all the rest. I'm tired of it and I just want them gone.

Comment: I do not see this on my Windows 10 machine. Try to show a screen shot in your question.

Comment: Added. If you don't see them on your machine, that would be interesting.

Comment: In the menu bar you cannot remove these. I just never use them. You appear to be right clicking on My PC.  I use Explorer from the Task Bar and the Tiles icon does not show up.  You can use Explorer in a way that does not show Tiles.  Otherwise it is not anything to worry about.

Comment: No, I don't think that is correct.